# The Tunnelling Man

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, quantum-tunneling

What's the probability that I will *tunnel* through a solid wall?

By "tunnel" I mean, the probability of finding me on the other side of the wall.

**Assumptions**

- Wall thickness = $d$
- Clearly state any other assumptions required for your solution: e.g. assumptions about the environment, geometry of set-up, etc.

Comment: You are already on the other side of the wall - at a distance of about 40,000 km. This question is too broad and ill-defined - and smells of a homework question. ("clearly state any other assumptions...")

Comment: @Floris The question is meant to stimulate one's imagination by galvanizing them to put-forward interesting solutions, which will depend on the assumptions made.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't feel galvanized. I will step aside and let others do their thing.

Comment: I could tell you if I assumed that you were a giant clump of non-interacting n=1 hydrogen atoms that numbers enough to make up the mass of a human body. If I really wanted to be fancy, instead of assuming n=1 for all atoms, I could make each one draw n from a Boltzmann distribution at room temperature.

But I haven't even the faintest clue if that's anywhere near resembling a reasonable approximation for the actual joint wave function of all the particles of your body.

Comment: @Bridgeburners I think that's a good place to start

Comment: The tunneling of macroscopic objects can be readily achieved with hammer and chisel or, for those requiring larger tunnels, with a tunnel boring machine.

Answer (score 2):

The probability of just one of your atoms getting through the wall is very low, multiply that probability (which is way lower than 1) by the probabilty that **all** of your atoms go through, you get a number so small that the universe would almost certainly have ended long before you got through the wall.

A 70 Kg  human body has approximately 7 X $10^{27}$ atoms, each of which has to get through the wall.

Environmental conditions would have no real effect, unless it was very hot and easier for your atoms to split up and tunnel, but you would be dead from the heat before that happened.

Comment: If $p$ is the probability of one atom getting through, the probability of all atoms is $\approx p^N$ where $N$ is the total number of atoms. This assumes incoherent co-tunneling.